# Controlling multiple inputs without a common ground using semiconductors

Tags: ground, isolation

I have a processor with GPIO outputs. It uses 3.3v logic outputs which share a common ground. (In particular, it has internal pull-up resistors, but I  could turn on open collector mode)

A device I need to control does not share common ØV grounds between inputs. (In particular, a number keypad on a handheld device.) The device only looks for a short betweeen the two points, and has no continuity between the "ground" of each switch. If I do attach grounds to a common point, the device will begin to false trigger and loose it's ability to determine which input is closed. Because it is designed for pushbuttons, not electronic triggering, a common ground does not matter in it's case.

[image]

Using discrete semiconductors (not relays, they are way to big and overrated current wise), how can I control many devices that do NOT share a common ground?

I do know of optoisolators, but I would really like an alternative semiconductor solution circuit (basic transistors, diodes, etc...) if it is possible.

Comment: optoisolators are a semiconductor solution

Comment: if you are specifically trying to avoid optoisolators though, there are digital isolators, but are more expensive and harder to source depending on where you are (e.g. ISO150, MAX14850, etc)

Comment: So there is no way of simulating key presses using basic transistor logic?

Comment: There is but I cant think of a way of doing it using transistors and keeping grounds isolated

Comment: So after looking at it some more, I have figured out that rows have common ground, and columbs have common positive lines. It is still the same problem

Comment: Try analog switches. The power supply to the analog switches needs to be higher than the highest voltage of the inputs.

Comment: Analog devices has a large range of digital isolators: http://www.analog.com/en/products/interface-isolation/isolation/standard-digital-isolators.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how "isolated" you need your solution to be.

Given the example above, where the switching voltages are unknown, possibly variable, but fairly small ... let's say they are bounded by some analog supply rails, +/-15V or 0/15V.

Then there's a huge range of analog FET switches designed for this purpose, which translate 0/5V logic inputs to on/off states for FETs anywhere within this range. ON resistance may be 5 or 50 ohms (varying by a few percent as the analog voltage varies from rail to rail), off resistange of many megohms up to a gigohm.

Often used for audio switching in hi-fi and broadcast applications

Good enough?

They were made by Analog Devices, Intersil, Harris, Siliconix and others, no doubt absorbed into other companies...

You'll find four SPST switches in a package, dual 4:1 multiplexers, DPDT and the other normal range of switch configurations.

Examples : DG508 and many others.

[Farnell's part selector](http://uk.farnell.com/analogue-switches) will give you some idea what's available in terms of switch configuration, supply voltage, ON resistance etc.